# I'm unable to set cookies for ChromeDriver running in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my selenium tests using ChromeDriver in headless mode addCookie method calls cause exception; the tests all work in normal mode

My Chrome Browser version is 75.0.3770.90 and ChromeDriver version is 75.0.3770.8. The OS is Mac OS X 10.14.5

The exception I'm getting is:

```java
    org.openqa.selenium.UnableToSetCookieException: unable to set cookie
    (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.90)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'A0353.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:84c:de05:352a:4bcc%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome,         browserVersion: 75.0.3770.90, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe7..., userDataDir: /var/folders/nc/gqkjhl8920j...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63795}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
    Session ID: db1528ca16e944bb6596563337e1ba40
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.addCookie(RemoteWebDriver.java:682)
    at com.anatwine.testing.common.selenium.PageObject.addCookie(PageObject.java:187)
    at com.anatwine.testing.component.page.landingpage.LandingPage.addUsernameAndRolesCookies(LandingPage.java:54)
    at com.anatwine.testing.component.steps.portallandingpage.RoleBasedAuthorisationSteps.lambda$new$347(RoleBasedAuthorisationSteps.java:32)
    at com.anatwine.testing.component.steps.portallandingpage.RoleBasedAuthorisationSteps$$Lambda$494/785340693.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java8.Java8StepDefinition.execute(Java8StepDefinition.java:112)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:63)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:49)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:44)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$1.run(Runtime.java:84)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:220)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:81)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
    at ✽.A user has 'ROLE_LANDING,ROLE_BRAND_ORDERSIM' roles(feature/component/portal-landingpage/PortalLandingPageRoleAuthorisations.feature:12)
```

The code causing the problem is:

```java
    driver.get(initialPageUrl);    
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, encode(cookieValue, "UTF-8"), "localhost","/", null);
    driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you added the cookie before navigating to the site. You should first navigate to your url

```java
driver.get("yourWebPage");
```

and only after this add cookies

```java
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

For a better analysis of what is going wrong, if above won't help, you have to add more code of your program.

Also maybe duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842709/unable-to-set-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: I did load an initial page first, otherwise it won't work even in the normal mode.

Comment: @ShaTao Can you add the whole stacktrace? It is not enough one line to analyze deeper your problem

Comment: Full stack trace added.

Comment: @ShaTao are your _initialPageUrl_ is localhost or don't contain dots? It can be some problems with this, the explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set)
Also, I can suggest trying the same example with other values (some test values, like 'abc') while you create cookie variable, maybe problem with some of the values

Answer (score 1):

It looks in the headless mode you MUST have protocol in the page url while in the normal mode the web driver defaults to http. So once we replaced "localhost:8080/path" with "http://localhost:8080/path" it worked.