# How to set document.cookie in selenium

Tags: selenium, cookies, document

I'm struggling with setting "document.cookie" value via Selenium. I want to achieve something like this. Generally, when I'm on a real browser like Chrome, I open the console and type

```
document.cookie='my_secret_cookie=1;path=/'
```

And everything works like a charm.

How can I achieve this via Selenium? Currently, I've done something like this, but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
Date today    = new Date();
Date tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
Cookie newCookie = new Cookie.Builder("myCookie","my_secret_cookie=1")
                .domain("my.site") // declared in my local.properties file
                .path("/")
                .expiresOn(tomorrow) 
                .isSecure(true) 
                .build(); 

driver.manage().addCookie(newCookie);
```

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set cookies in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842709/unable-to-set-cookies-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @RyanWilson not really. When I'm trying to do it I'm getting the error: UnableToSetCookieException: unable to set cookie